# Окончание в существительном

Tags: окончания

Ожидайте поступленИЯ средств / Ожидайте поступленИЕ средств

Как правильно?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Здесь первый, с родительным падежом лучше. Вообще глагол "ждать" с производными сейчас все активнее использует родительный падеж дополнения. Когда речь идет о неконкретном, не фиксированном по времени и месту событии, родительный - норма. 
Другими словами, можно равноправно ***ожидать поезд, холодА, платеж*** и ***ожидать поезда, холодов, платежа*** - с несколько раздичным смыслом.
Но при этом желательно только ***ожидать прибытия поезда, наступления холодов, поступления платежа*** и т. д. Иное выглядит косноязычно.

Comment: @behemothus вот нашел словарную статью (p.s. что такое производные?) http://upravlenie.academic.ru/1437